# Binding event without eventhandler..why it works?

Tags: c#, events

I simply do not understand why both works:

```
this.timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
this.timer.Tick += classA.Tick;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from v2.0 (AFAIR) of C#, `EventHandler` (and other delegates too) is instantiated implicitly. If you'll decompile your code you'll see that.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

> Any method from any accessible class or struct that matches the delegate's signature, which consists of the return type and parameters, can be assigned to the delegate.